# JDBC to Oracle DB: connection.getMetaData() takes forever - any clue why and how to speed this up?

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g

Our application at startup checks for the presence of certain tables, sequences and a few other things. We had programmed that straight forward like so:

```
...
MetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
...
ResultSet tables = meta.getTables(...);
... <checking for the presences of specific tables>
ResultSet sequences = meta.getSequences(...);
... <checking for the presences of specific sequences>
etc.
...
```

While so far the initial `connection.getMetaData()`-call always had a sub-second duration, after moving to a bigger, more powerful and shared Oracle DB Server this call now reproducibly takes more than 5 minutes(!). This time goes directly to the startup time of our application which has more than quadrupled by this and that is of course a big no-go!

Any idea why this JDBC call takes so long on one system but not on another? And are there any options or settings that could speed this up? Both databases report as "Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production". Both servers are in our intranet, so network-wise they should be similarly reachable. The new one CPU- and RAM-wise much more powerful and is configured in a fail-over config (i.e. the connection URL contains 2 servers in case one is down or not reachable). The old one was a simple one-machine setup.

Anything else that could be relevant to this or explain why that call now takes that much longer?

Addendum:

We tried to debug into the method (but didn't get very far). But the culprit seems to be in `DatabaseMetadata.initSequences()`, i.e. it seems that the fetching of the sequences is the part that takes so long on this server while it took split-seconds on the other. Any wisdom what could be causing this?

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar

Comment: There isn't a ```getSequences(...)``` or ```initSequences()``` method in ```DatabaseMetadata```. Could you paste a short working example? Keep in mind that data catalog operations can vary widely in different Oracle databases, depending on how many schemas there are, how many schema objects there are, and stats.

Answer (score 0):

We found the culprit of our slow Metadata query!
The reason is that during initialization we set the comparison mode to `LINGUISTIC`, i.e. we execute a:

```
alter session set nls_comp=LINGUISTIC;
```

With that setting active the retrieval of sequences (as part of the getMetaData()) takes ~5 minutes! If we leave it at the default (which is `alter session set nls_comp=BINARY`) then the fetching of the metadata takes ~1 second only!

Apparently that comparison mode leads to a full table scan which causes this crazy query duration. However, we need this comparison mode since otherwise many of our queries don't yield matches (in our case names, company names, adresses, etc.) that contain accented characters.

We "fixed" this issue by switching the comparison mode at a later point in the application after we have completed the startup checks that verify the presence of certain tables and sequences, etc.

If someone knows an approach, how to speed up the MetaData-creation even in the presence of a non-default comparison mode (e.g. can one create a special index or similar) - please let me know!

Obviously there must be some additional setting involved here, because - as mentioned - on our previous DB-server the MetaData-fetch had taken ~1 second only even with that mode set to LINGUISTIC.